# How to set product category base the same as shop base in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm using WooCommerce on a WordPress. I would like my products and product categories to have the same url base.
E.g.

```
www.example.com/shop/product-category
www.example.com/shop/sample-product
```

Using this code here:

```
    add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', function( $rules )
{
    $new_rules = array(
        'shop/([^/]*?)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'shop/([^/]*?)/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]',
    );
    return $new_rules + $rules;
} );
```

I changed the permalinks in Settings > permalink:

**Custom Structure:** /shop/%postname%/
**Product category base:** shop
**Custom base:** shop

then when visit each of the following pages, I get the following result:

**Custom Structure:** works 
**Product category base:** works
**Custom base:** 404 error

Anybody have any insight on how to get the single product pages to not throw the 404 error?

Thanks!

Comment: Help me, please!

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people dealing with the same issue and I haven't found a solution yet either.  It's like the whole thing is broken and most people just don't care?